# SQL Server, mass update of a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a table with a column that contains some text, different for each row of course. For each row, I would like to update this column by adding a prefix (the same one for each row) to the existing text. Basically, this is what I want to happen for each row.

Before: Column XXX = "Some existing text"
After: Column XXX = "ZZZ" + "Some existing text"

Is there a way to do this simply without updating each row one by one ?

Thank you

Comment: With the current description, I don't know why a standard `UPDATE` statement won't work e.g., `UPDATE yourtable SET  XXX = 'ZZZ' + XXX`. Indeed, this is one of the strengths of databases - doing updates on large amounts of rows at the same time rather than 1 at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update below will work for you

```
update table1
set XXX =concat('ZZZ',XXX );
```